# Distribution app phenomen

Tags: ios, xcode, itunes, provisioning, software-distribution

I'm making a .app with Distribution provisions and after ziping i uploading him to iTunes with "Application Loader".

All is fine, and .app is submitting at successfully.

But in some case, i see error

**Application failed codesign verification. The signature was invalid, contains disallowed entitlements, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate.**

And i **solving him** just:

1) Copy, paste folder with content, source, xcode project files to another folder

2) Rebuild app from new folder

3) Trying again to submit, and all is **fine**.

What's going up ?

**UPDATED**

Solved! In my mac this command is not working at perfectly

codesign --verify -vvv My.app

When error is exist, him told me

**Valid on disk**

But when i tryed this command at another Mac, then told a true error, and we solved this error.

*Mac OS version: 10.8.3, Xcode version: 4.6, Application Loader version: 2.8*

Comment: Are you not uploading directly from inside Xcode via the Archive function?

Comment: Here error is exist too . But after recopy a project folder, error is gone

Comment: It hold the old values related to the directory path and other references. You can upload the application from the xcode itself. It's very straight forward.

Comment: @aToz but i want compile a build in one mac, and send .zip file from another mac

Comment: @CReaTuS are you facing the same issue, when you try to build it through Xcode ?

Comment: @aToz Yes, if i try send through XCode i see this issue